# PlayonLinux not showing all options

Tags: kubuntu, wine, playonlinux

I have used playonlinux before and never encountered this issue.
I have Kubuntu Jammy 22.04 using PlayOnLinux 4.3.4.
I was able to useit to install a game already but it is not showing all the possibilities in its bar menu (see below the screenshot)
Any reason for that? How could I possibly fix it?

[Screenshot of the display of PoL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOhNR.png)

Comment: @Nmath Hi thanks for replying. This is what I am looking for actually more of this display especially that I do not seem to accessthe whole database either.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayOnLinux#/media/File:PlayOnLinux-Screenshot.png

Comment: @Nmath thanks for the follo up, definitely tried reinstalling it, whether via the deb file from the website, through the terminal or the discover app. Same thing everytime. I thought that could be to my display settings so I put everything to default but did notimprove anything at all.